# Get local date/time with Phonegap / AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, date, cordova, local

I'm developing an ios/android app using Phonegap/Cordova and AngularJS.
I'm trying to get the local date/time of the device, with no success...

```
new Date();
```

returns the UTC date/time in a Date object.

```
navigator.globalization.dateToString
```

gives me a formatted local date/time in a String object.

Is there a way to get the local date/time in a Date object ?
For example, I would like to use getHours() on that object to get the local hour, any ideas ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can convert the string to date object.

Code sample: (assuming the date is on format YYYY-MM-DD)

```
var string = "2010-01-10".split('-');
var dateObject = new Date(Number(string[0]),Number(string[1]) -1 ,Number(string[2]));
```

The idea is to initialize the [`Date()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp) with 3 arguments: `new Date(YEAR, MONTH, DATE);`

Split the string in any format you want, as long as you can extract the YEAR, MONTH, DATE values and convert them to integers.

Comment: Yes but navigator.globalization.dateToString can return "2010-01-10" or "10/01/2010" or other date format in a local set. Your code will work only for US date format, am i wrong ?

Comment: Thanks Muhammad, I'm gonna write a parser for different cases.